# Entity Framework Core: DBCommand is executed fast but the total time is 10x slower

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using EF Core 3.1 + PostrgeSql. After executing:

```cs
var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var entity1 = await _context.Entity1
    .Include(e => e.Entity2)
    .Include(e => e.Entity3)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.Entity4)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == someId);

stopWatch.Stop();
_logger.LogInformation($"Elapsed: {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds.");
```

next logs can be seen:

```
[16:49:36 INF] Executed DbCommand (43ms) [Parameters=[@__Id_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT t."Id", ....
...
ORDER BY ....
[16:49:36 INF] Elapsed: 400 milliseconds.
```

I can see that `DBCommand` is executed `43ms`. If I take the logged SELECT query and execute it against the DB, it will take about the same time. Query returns 45 columns and 2000 rows dataset.

But the overall time is almost ten times more: `400ms`.

The questions are:

- What is the additional time about? Is it the time EF spends on creating C# objects?
- Is it possible to reduce it?

What I tried:

- I tried to use `AsNoTracking()`. It seems it doesn't give any effect here.

Comment: Do u have proper indexes defined in DB on these tables?

Comment: `returns 45 columns and 2000 rows` how long will it take for those 90K values to get returned over the network connection? Do any of those columns contain large strings? When you run a query in SSMS long strings are truncated at 65K characters. Do you really need all those columns?

Comment: @DA, The tables are indexed properly. As you can see, the query itself executes quite fast.
@PanagiotisKanavos, I wonder if `Executed DbCommand (43ms)` log record includes already the time of getting the dataset? I would say yes, because it logs after DbCommand got the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, EF will take some time to construct and associate the entities. Something to check for a fair comparison is whether the DbContext is "warmed up" prior to your test or not. The first query executed against a DbContext will always incur the one-time configuration cost. The larger your domain model is, the steeper this cost can be. So if it is possible that this test executes against the DbContext for the very first time:

```
var temp = _context.Entity1.Any(); // Run a simple initial query which will ensure the one-off config cost is not being counted.

var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var entity1 = await _context.Entity1
    .Include(e => e.Entity2)
    .Include(e => e.Entity3)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.Entity4)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == someId);

stopWatch.Stop();
_logger.LogInformation($"Elapsed: {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds.");
```

Something else that can factor into query performance is resolving tracked instances, though if you are seeing no different in performance with `AsNoTracking()` then this is not a factor in your case. Hoewver, for future reference when you have a DbContext that has loaded, and is tracking a fair number of entities that may, or may not be related to entities being loaded in a particular query; If you run that query with tracking then not only will the DbContext keep tracking references of any entities loaded, but it will go through *all* relatable entities to look for tracked instances related to entities you requested and associate them, whether you told it to eager load or not.

For example:

```
var children = _context.Children.Where(x => x.ParentId < 5).ToList();

var parent1 = _context.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
var parent6 = _context.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == 6);
```

When we load the two parents, even though we don't explicitly eager load children with `Include`, because an earlier tracked query against the DbContext loaded children of parents 1 through 5, when you inspect parent #1, it will have it's children collection loaded, parent #6 will not. This can lead to situational behaviour, and show a performance cost that applies to both parent queries as the DbContext will scan through all tracked references to see if there is anything to associate to either parent when loaded. Loading the parents with `AsNoTracking()` even if the children were loaded and tracked will result in just the parent being returned, and without the cost of the DbContext scanning the tracked entities for references to fill.

A tip for improving performance when you do need to eager load an entity graph is to reduce the Cartesian Product by using `AsSplitQuery()`. Instead of generating a single query with JOINs, it will instead build separate queries for the related entities, resulting in far fewer records being pulled. In a situation where 1 record has 10 As and 10 Bs, with 20 Cs, the cartesian pulls back 2000 rows. With `AsSplitQuery()` it would pull back 41 rows. Using AsSplitQuery() isn't a silver bullet as there can be issues with things like sorting and pagination if these are a factor of the query.

The best way to minimize the impact of Cartestian Products and tracked references is to use Projection as much as possible. Rather than fetching entities and their relatives, use `Select` or `ProjectTo` (Automapper) to fetch just the columns from the entity graph you need. This automatically avoids issues with adding to, or searching tracking caches, and with fewer columns, the size of the resulting Cartesian can be reduced, with the populated result generally being simpler/flatter than an entity object graph.

Hopefully that gives you a few avenues to look at. EF will always incur a bit of a premium to querying over raw SQL, but it generally shouldn't be a case of many multiples slower, and provide a lot of capability for the cost it does add.

Comment: Without seeing the schema, `.AsSplitQuery()`  is a good option but projections is often the best solution if in your final processing you don't need all the rows. It's a good writeup, I would also include the option of trying the same query on a `new` instance of the DBContext to remove the possibility of EF linking existing records.

Comment: Yep, a new instance was one of my go-to suggestions in earlier questions though checking with `AsNoTracking` accomplishes the same thing. I had originally though it just prevented loaded instances from entering the tracking cache, but it also completely ignores the tracking cache for entities and associations on read as well. (Effectively acting the same as a fresh DbContext)